# How can I generate a uuid/guid in MariaDB 10.1?

Tags: mariadb

I have a `BINARY(16)` column since MariaDB 10.1 doesn't support GUID fields yet. I was hoping to use mysql's `random_bytes(16)` function to generate some guid's in a query (or even as a default value?). Unfortunately this is not available in mariadb so I'm looking for an alternative that isn't terrible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [article on GUIDs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/guiduuid-performance/) in MariaDB knowledge base, and a stored function that would generate a BINARY(16) sequential UUID.  To generate a 36-byte UUID as string, use *UUID()* function.

Comment: The function name to create a 36-byte UUID-as-a-string is called ,surprisingly, UUID() :) https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/uuid/

Comment: How do you have `UUID()` as default value for a field?

Comment: easily. `create table t (u uuid default uuid())` thats in the newer versions that support UUID as type. In the older versions, `create table t2(u char(36) default uuid())`